# ImageView: getWidth() different from getLayoutParams().width?

Tags: android, imageview, width, layoutparams

That's my source code to create a new ImageView:

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.width = screen_dimens(0.5, "w");
            params.height = screen_dimens(0.5, "w");
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

(`screen_dimens(0.5, "w")`=50% of screen width)

But now when I want to get the width of the Image, I get the following results:
image.getWidth() => 0
image.getLayoutParams().width => 360

Now what is the difference between those two functions? And how can I set the Image-width so the `getWidth()` method also returns the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to set width and height :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 6):

Even you have set width and height for a ImageView or any View by using LayoutParams,
imageView.getWidth() always returns 0 until it is drawn in its parent.

Comment: this explains the asnwer for the above question

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
    image.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            image.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    });
```

instead of

```
   image.getWidth()
```